# The option "constraints" does not exist

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using Symfony 2.6. I am trying to create a form without Entity, but get the following error:

> The option "constraints" does not exist. Known options are: "action",
>   "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound",
>   "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider",
>   "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class",
>   "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "inherit_data",
>   "intention", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped",
>   "max_length", "method", "pattern", "post_max_size_message",
>   "property_path", "read_only", "required", "translation_domain",
>   "trim", "virtual".

```
    class MessageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sender', 'text', [
                'constraints' => [
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('recipient', 'email')
            ->add('message', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'message';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Constraints\Collection(array(
            'fields' => [
                'sender' => [
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                    new Constraints\Email(),
                ],
                'recipient' => [
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                    new Constraints\Email(),
                ],
                'message' => [
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                ],
            ],

        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'validation_constraints' => $collectionConstraint,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Using only setDefaultOptions shows no error, but it does not work, does not validate the fields.

As can be seen, tried anyway. I also tried as is the documentation for using the component form outbox, but get the same error.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#form-validation

**EDIT**

I also tried this way and get the same error.

```
    $form = $formFactory->createBuilder()
    ->add('task', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
    ))
    ->add('dueDate', 'date', array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(),
            new Type('\DateTime'),
        )
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

Comment: I feel like what you're trying to do is perfectly valid. Since nothing rings a bell here I would set a breakpoint in `buildForm` and try following `Symfony` to see why does it fail...

Comment: Are you sure this error comes from the `constraints` option you try to add to the `sender` text input, and not from somewhere else in your code? I don't see what's wrong either.

Comment: Yes I Understand. I did exactly as it is in Symfony documentation and still the same error.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite old question, I just found it, so the problem still appears time to time.

I did like in docs:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html

```
$validator = Validation::createValidator();

    $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
        ...
        ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
        ...
        ->getFormFactory();
```

and don't forget about use of course:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension;
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'constraints' option is part of `ValidatorExtension` which is not part of core form extensions. `TypeTestCase` it only loads core form extensions. Adding following code fixes the issue.

```
protected function getExtensions()
{
    return [new ValidatorExtension(Validation::createValidator())];
}
```

For more information https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html#adding-custom-extensions

Answer (score 2):

The 'constraints' option is part of the Validator extension form. How I solved the problem:

```
$ValidatorExtension = new ValidatorExtension($validatorBuilder->getValidator());

$formRegistry = new FormRegistry([$csrfProvider, new CoreExtension(), $ValidatorExtension], Yii::$symfony->container->get('form.resolved_type_factory'));
```

Comment: I added this answer so that this question doesn't appear on the *unanswered* page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony?sort=unanswered